# How do I create a gap in an outline or shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, pathfinder

I'm looking for a way to create a gap in an outline or shape. The options in pathfinder are not helping.

[image: Outline with red circle to designate area to make gap]

Comment: Really? You haven't tried the Pen Tool? Or the Scissor and Eraser tools?

Comment: I think the -Votes are a bit harsh, its not at all obvious how to do this looking at the tool bar.

Comment: But looking at the help files it's immediately obvious. Even a basic [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=cut+a+path+in+Illustrator&hl=en&biw=1172&bih=1426&site=imghp&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAGoVChMI8qWS0ZCGxgIVjCCsCh1EuwAT&dpr=1) makes it pretty obvious. My down vote was for *clear* lack of effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the path you want to edit. Use the **Scissors tool** and click on the path at both ends of the gap you'd like to create. Then use the **Selection tool** (black arrow tool) to click the portion to remove and click delete.

[image: Scissors tool screen grab]

**Before** [image: Screen grab of Before]  **After** [image: Screen grab of After]

**Tip:** Adding guides to the document to help guide you on where to apply the Scissors is a good idea, too, but not necessary. If you do that, Lock the guides `View > Guides > Lock Guides` or you might cut the guide instead of the path.